# How can we know the user logging in through linkedin profile is an employee or an employer?

Tags: php, codeigniter, linkedin-api

i am using linkedin API. it's my first time with any API. 
I want to know that how can we know that the user logging in through his/her linkedin account is an employee or an employer.

I am getting the information through

```
$profile = $this->linkedin->profile('~:(id,first-name,last-name,email-address,headline,picture-url,location,skills,summary,main-address,projects)');
```

There is also a method like this:

```
$this->linkedin->company('1337:(id,name,ticker,description,logo-url,locations:(address,is-headquarters))');
```

I am confused how can I perform this task... Any kind of help will be very much appreciative. Thanks.

Comment: I'm fairly confident LinkedIn doesn't know this information, so there's no way it could be in the API. The best way I can think to do it, is if you can get their job title, look for the word "owner" or something - but its far from foolproof.

Comment: thanks alot.. I think the same.. and what you said about the job title I discussed it with my senior but same as you said. it's far from foolproof..

Comment: actually at first I was redirecting the user to a signup form where the user could select from the drop down whether employee or employer.. but the requirement is we should not ask we should get it from linkedin and automatically label the user as employee or an employer.. and afterwards we have to show the user's linkedin feed on our website..